# Infographic and charts on a Website

Tags: jquery, flash, html, svg

I want to create this infographic( Teaser ;) ) on http://www.bcndevcon.org website

The problem:

If I use **Flash** I won't be able to display any information on iOS devices BUT i will be able to perform animations if I want to feed in in realtime.

If I use **HTML5** I won't be able to display it on any IE, and animations will be slow...

Finally I'm not really sure **SVG** is a great solution so...

Any suggestion!?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hohoho, I got to see a teaser for free :)  Looks quite good.

I think you can bet that most developers won't be using IE. Use HTML5.

Also, take a look at highcharts, maybe it has the functionality that you need and you can use it for free for open-source projects.

http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

Raphael JS may also be an option for you.

http://raphaeljs.com/